# How do I retrieve Mac Address on WP8 or WP8.1 from native code (C++)

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I need to get the mac address of the wp at C++ layer.
That's part of the protocal of the software.
And.... I searched a lot,
I couldn't find a proper method....
So do you guys have some ideas how.....

Thank you for the taking time read and answer.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the MAC address in a Windows Phone Store app, sorry.